# Clickhouse node can’t recognize itself

Tags: replication, clickhouse

So I started to have some pretty unique clickhouse error on one of my environment:

```
Creating table query failed with code: 159\nname: DB::Exception\nmessage: DB::Exception: Watching task /clickhouse/task_queue/ddl/query-0000016373 is executing longer than distributed_ddl_task_timeout (=180) seconds. There are 4 unfinished hosts (0 of them are currently active), they are going to execute the query in background\nstack: 0.
```

After some investigation I realize that Clickhouse node can’t recognize itself and that verify by the `system.clusters` table:

```sql
SELECT
    cluster,
    shard_num,
    replica_num,
    host_name,
    host_address,
    port,
    is_local
FROM system.clusters;

┌─cluster──────────────────────────────┬─shard_num─┬─replica_num─┬─host_name─────────────────┬─host_address─┬─port─┬─is_local─┐
│ ClickHouseCluster                    │         1 │           1 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-0 │ 10.10.0.5    │ 9000 │        0 │
│ ClickHouseCluster                    │         1 │           2 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-1 │ 10.10.0.10   │ 9000 │        0 │
│ ClickHouseCluster                    │         2 │           1 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-2 │ 10.10.0.11   │ 9000 │        0 │
│ ClickHouseCluster                    │         2 │           2 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-3 │ 10.10.0.13   │ 9000 │        0 │
│ DistributedHandlesReplicationCluster │         1 │           1 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-0 │ 10.10.0.5    │ 9000 │        0 │
│ DistributedHandlesReplicationCluster │         1 │           2 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-1 │ 10.10.0.10   │ 9000 │        0 │
│ DistributedHandlesReplicationCluster │         2 │           1 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-2 │ 10.10.0.11   │ 9000 │        0 │
│ DistributedHandlesReplicationCluster │         2 │           2 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-3 │ 10.10.0.13   │ 9000 │        0 │
│ OneShardManualReplicationCluster     │         1 │           1 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-0 │ 10.10.0.5    │ 9000 │        0 │
│ OneShardManualReplicationCluster     │         1 │           2 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-1 │ 10.10.0.10   │ 9000 │        0 │
│ OneShardManualReplicationCluster     │         1 │           3 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-2 │ 10.10.0.11   │ 9000 │        0 │
│ OneShardManualReplicationCluster     │         1 │           4 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-3 │ 10.10.0.13   │ 9000 │        0 │
│ all-replicated                       │         1 │           1 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-0 │ 10.10.0.5    │ 9000 │        0 │
│ all-replicated                       │         1 │           2 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-1 │ 10.10.0.10   │ 9000 │        0 │
│ all-replicated                       │         1 │           3 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-2 │ 10.10.0.11   │ 9000 │        0 │
│ all-replicated                       │         1 │           4 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-3 │ 10.10.0.13   │ 9000 │        0 │
│ all-sharded                          │         1 │           1 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-0 │ 10.10.0.5    │ 9000 │        0 │
│ all-sharded                          │         2 │           1 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-1 │ 10.10.0.10   │ 9000 │        0 │
│ all-sharded                          │         3 │           1 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-2 │ 10.10.0.11   │ 9000 │        0 │
│ all-sharded                          │         4 │           1 │ solutiontest-clickhouse-3 │ 10.10.0.13   │ 9000 │        0 │
└──────────────────────────────────────┴───────────┴─────────────┴───────────────────────────┴──────────────┴──────┴──────────┘
```

But when I check the host name on one of my cluster it seem to be correct:

```bash
$ hostname --fqdn
solutiontest-clickhouse-0.europe-west4-b.c.opensee-ci.internal

$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.10.0.5 solutiontest-clickhouse-0.europe-west4-b.c.opensee-ci.internal solutiontest-clickhouse-0  # Added by Google
169.254.199.254 metadata.google.internal  # Added by Google

$ cat /etc/hostname
solutiontest-clickhouse-0
```

Comment: do you use default_database in your <remote_servers> configuration settings?

Answer (score 2):

I think we'll need to take a closer look at this with your clickhouse-server logs. I'd suggest please opening a case here: https://clickhouse.cloud/support so that we can securely get your logs uploaded and investigate further what's happening.

Full disclosure: I work for ClickHouse Support

Thanks

Comment: P.S. my best guess is that your cluster configuration hostnames do not exactly match the hostnames reported on the systems, but as you noted you checked this on at least one: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/22410

Answer (score 0):

There is a article about that problem here but no solution is given
https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-setup-and-maintenance/altinity-kb-ddlworker/there-are-n-unfinished-hosts-0-of-them-are-currently-active/